# Looker Dashboard Query

Tags: sql, dashboard, looker

I am new to Looker and creating a dashboard. I have to get the previous device of customers who have purchased a particular product. For example,
user A has purchased

1. 'Phone 1' on 1st July 2022
2. 'Phone 2' on 12th May 2022
3. 'Phone 3' on 10th Jan 2022

Now I am looking at Phone 1 purchasers (for which user A qualifies) and want to see what was the last smartphone these purchasers owned. In the case of user A, it will be 'Phone 2'.

I have fields like 'customer id', 'smartphone names', and 'date'.

I have tried this by writing code in SQL runner but I cannot find a way to save the look.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be getting the LoomML code after running your SQL query in SQL Runner, as shown in the below pic. Then using it, create a derived table in LookML and include it in an explore. Then you would be able to use that explore and save visualization as a look or dashboard.

[image].